# How to set style display: none to a query before and after the angular animation?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a big angular-material form split into smaller peaces, and I want to animate between the mat-cards I put the controls in. I used *ngIf to show and hide the cards, but initializing the content makes the animation rough, so I want to use display none instead of it. I could not figure it out how to hide the card from other steps.

This is my simplified component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "material-app",
  templateUrl: "app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["app.component.scss"],
  animations: [
    trigger("state", [
      //state("state2", style({ display: "none" })),
      transition("state1 => state2", [
        group([
          query('#card2', [style({display: 'none', opacity: 0})]),
          query("#card1", [
            animate(
              `${AnimationDurations.EXITING} ${
                AnimationCurves.ACCELERATION_CURVE
              }`,
              style({ transform: "translateY(56px)", opacity: 0, display: 'none' })
            )
          ])
        ]),
        query("#card2", [
          style({ opacity: 0, display: '*' }),
          group([
            style({
              transform: "translateY(-56px)",
              opacity: 0
            }),
            animate(
              `${AnimationDurations.ENTERING} ${
                AnimationCurves.DECELERATION_CURVE
              }`,
              style("*")
            )
          ])
        ])
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  state = 'state1';
  reset() {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.state = 'state1'
    }, 500)
  }
}
```

And this would be my temaplate

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="state">
        <mat-radio-button value="state1">State 1</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="state2">State 2</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" [@trigger]="state" (@trigger.done)="reset()">
    <mat-card id="card1">Card 1</mat-card>
    <mat-card id="card2">Card 2</mat-card>
</div>
```

**I woudl like to hide `#card2` when the `state === state1` and vice versa. The animation works correctly, but before and after it both cards are visible.**

My stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-switch-card-animation

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you, try such code:

```
    <mat-card id="card1" [style.display]="state=='state1'?'block':'none'">Card 1</mat-card>
    <mat-card id="card2" [style.display]="state=='state2'?'block':'none'">Card 2</mat-card>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this too, but this hides #card1 immediately, not after the transition. @roma-ruzich

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution but in my example just try to use it in your project,

I have had this issue with angular 7

```
  animations: [
trigger('openClose', [
  // ...
  state('open', style({
    'height': '20px', 'width':'120px', 'opacity': '1'
  })),
  state('closed', style({
    'height': '0','width':'0', 'opacity': '0'
  })),
  transition('open => closed', [
    animate('1s')
  ]),
  transition('closed => open', [
    animate('0.5s')
  ]),
]),]
```

and in the component

```
  isOpen = true
  toggle() {
     this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
```

and it is

```
      Click to toggle the animation : <button (click)="toggle()" style="cursor: pointer;" aria-label="Example delete icon">
    {{isOpen? 'Hide input' : 'Display input'}}
  </button>
  <input style="margin-left:10px" [@openClose]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'" class="open-close-container" placeholder="" />
```

Here is the demo

[stackblitz angular -7 display style solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1cjddv)